# What does "spill out over my bottom lip" mean here?

Tags: meaning, literature

I would like to know what "spill out over my bottom lip" means in the following sentences:

> This is crazy, I think. I don’t have to drink it. I’m a
> thirty-four-year-old woman. I don’t even know these people, they have
> no hold over me. I won’t be made to do it—
>
> ‘Down it . . .’
>
> ‘Down it!’
>
> God, they’ve started to chant.
>
> ‘Save the Queen!’
>
> ‘She’s drowning!’
>
> ‘*Down it down it down it.*’
>
> I can feel my cheeks reddening. To get their eyes off me, to stop
> their chanting, I knock the glass back and gulp it all down. I’d
> thought the champagne was delicious before but it’s awful like this,
> sour and sharp, stinging my throat as I cough mid-swallow, rushing up
> inside my nose. I feel some of it **spill out over my bottom lip.** I
> feel my eyes tear up. I’m humiliated. It’s like everyone has
> understood the rules of whatever is happening. Everyone but me.

- Lucy Foley, *The Guest List*, Chapter 12

This is a thriller novel published in 2020 in the United Kingdom. One hundred and fifty guests would be gathering at some remote and deserted fictional islet called Inis an Amplóra off the coast of the island of Ireland to celebrate the wedding between Jules (a self-made woman running an online magazine called *The Download*) and Will (a celebrity appearing in a TV show program called *Survive the Night*). The day before the actual wedding day, Hannah, the wife of Charlie (Jules' friend), arrived at the island and is now at the dinner party for the rehearsal dinner with only some selected guests. And during the party, Hannah is now being forced to drink her champagne which is filled to the top, because someone put a penny in her glass.

In this part, I wonder what it means that some of champagne "spilled out *over* my bottom lip."
Would that mean that, some of champagne that was once in her mouth, spilled out of her mouth, and was now *over (=upon)* on her bottom lip?

Or, would that mean that some of champagne flowed *over (=overcoming the obstacle of)* the bottom lip and was flowing down? (These are just my guesses...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> some of champagne "spilled out over my bottom lip."

In the text, the person tries to swallow some champagne, but they involuntarily *cough*, and some of it comes back up. They feel it in their nose, and some of it comes out of their mouth.

A "spill" is an accident. Describing it this way emphasises that it was not their intention. Perhaps they tried to keep the champagne in their mouth by keeping their mouth closed, but as a result of the cough, some of the champagne flowed out of their mouth and they felt it 'spill out' over their bottom lip. It also helps create a visual image of the liquid perhaps running down their chin as it spilled over, rather than 'spurting' out in a spray.

Comment: Dear Astralbee, thank you very much for the explanation! So it was from her mouth that the champagne spilled out, and consequently, it was over her bottom lip. I think I was confused because there was no description regarding her mouth, so I wondered whether the spilling could have been originated from her nose or something, because the champagne "rushed up inside my nose" in the previous sentence. So I just wanted to ask your opinion. Then it was from her mouth that the champagne spilled out, and onto the bottom lip! I sincerely appreciate your help. :)